How many layers of graham's number are required to beat TREE(3)?
I have recently found out about the TREE function, and how TREE(3) is unimaginably large. I also learned about Graham's number, which is a lot smaller than TREE(3). Yet, is there some way to find out if there is a point where g(n) > TREE(3), where g(n) is the layer of Graham's number.
I know TREE(1) = 1 and TREE(2) = 3, which is beaten by g(1) and g(2). But is there another point where g(n) crosses TREE(3)? Furthermore, is there a point where g(n) permanently beats TREE(N)?

TREE(n) is on a whole other level from g(n). g(n) is level $\omega+1$ in the Fast Growing Hierarchy and the weak tree(n) (much weaker than strong TREE(n)) is the level of the SVO in the FGH. If a function a(x) has a higher FGH level than b(x), then as x approaches infinity a(x)>b(x). This means TREE(n)>g(n) as n approaches infinity. Since TREE(N) is on a much higher level than g(n), the n such that g(n)>TREE(3) would be on the same level as TREE(3). So n~TREE(3).
.
Answers without explaination:
The n such that g(n)>TREE(3) is ~TREE(3)
As n approaches infinity, TREE(n)>g(n)
